# python replace strings with numbers

Tags: python

im building a system to sort some .log files in .txt format so that I later can send it to excel. There is 70+ files and in every file im scanning for a keyword, I get 100+ strings that I want to save in a .txt. I can get every string that I want and see from which .log file each log has ben taken, but now I want to rename the file that the .log came from with a corresponding number (one number for every file). I have tried counting loops, array and strings but I wont get I right....

```
import glob
import os
import itertools


def LogFile(filename, tester):
    message = []
    data = []
    with open(filename) as filesearch:   # open search file
        filesearch = filesearch.readlines()   # read file

    file = filename[39:]

    for line in filesearch:
        if tester in line:   # extract ""
            start = '-> '
            end = ':\ '
            number = line[line.find(start)+3: line.find(end)]        #[ord('-> '):ord(' :\ ')]
            data.append(number)   # store all found wors in array

            text = line[line.find(end)+3:]
            message.append(text)

    with open('Msg.txt', 'a') as handler:  # create .txt file
        for i in range(len(data)):
            handler.write(f"{file}|{data[i]}|{message[i]}")

# open with 'w' to "reset" the file.
with open('Msg.txt', 'w') as file_handler:
    pass
# ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------

for filename in glob.glob(r'C:\Users\\Desktop\Access\*.log'):
    LogFile(filename, 'Sending Request: Tester')
```

How its now

```
from .txt file  
GTX77_ 2017-05-20_1209.log|166 9 02 F
GTX77_ 2017-08-24_1209.log|166 9 03 F
JBB 925_1720_1400.log|161 9 02 F 
JBB 925_1724_1900.log|161 9 12 F
```

How I want it

```
new .txt file
1|166 9 02 F
1|166 9 03 F
2|161 9 02 F
2|161 9 12 F
```

So my question is if there is some function that can change the variable "filename" to a corresponding number instead (ex, all .log files from file GTX77.log gets index 1 instead, and all .log from JBB925 gets index 2...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a dictionary for that. you initialize it for every filename then you can recover the index with `get(filename, default_value)`

```
i=1
d = {}
for filename in filenames:
   if not d.get(filename, False):
       d[filename] = i
       i+=1
```

Comment: thanks, i get it to replace number nu, but now it counts how many .log string each file has", i just wanted to count "each file" so that every .log string has the same number in each file, do you know how to make that happen to? (i have no clue :) )

Comment: I don't think I understood your question, please use the dict documentation or [this tutorial](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_dictionary.htm) in order to understand what is happening when you store de filename and its number.